# Developing NativeScript debugging cli tools for app?

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface, nativescript

I would like to create some commands that can be used to debug/test my NativeScript app. I have tried both readline from node.js and readline-sync - but I get errors using these. Is it possible read from the NativeScript console?

Using [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync) I get the following error message.

> JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined.platform')

related to this code in the module `IS_WIN = process.platform === 'win32'`

And using node I get:

> JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined.stdin')

And logging `process` to the console - prints undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes debug/test is possible in nativescript app using browser console and console using command like:-

```
tns debug android/ios
```

**OR**

```
tns debug android/ios --chrome
```